# Images occasionally not found or invalid on startup

Tags: android, xamarin

So I have an issue when launching an Android app written in Xamarin Forms.

Essentially none of the images load on start up. This is a rare occurrence and happens at complete random. The only thing I've noticed is that the system seems to stall slightly before it happens.

Log Cat shows:

```
D/ActivityManager(  624): bindService callerProcessName:[App i'm starting here], calleePkgName: com.android.providers.media, action: android.media.IMediaScannerService
W/ResourceType( 3893): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
I/mono-stdout( 3893): FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: Icons_Taskbar_logo.png
W/ResourceType( 3893): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
I/mono-stdout( 3893): FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: Icons_Taskbar_products.png
W/ResourceType( 3893): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
I/mono-stdout( 3893): FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: Icons_Taskbar_settings.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix for this was adding

```
ResourceManager.Init(GetType().Assembly);
```

As the first line in my OnCreate method.